# <input> not clickable after CSS transform rotateX

Tags: css, rotation, transform, clickable

I'm trying to show an input field when a certain link is clicked, using a nice transform transition. It's kind of a rollover effect, similar to iOS 6 notification animation style.

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yBzJL

Basically I just position the input field above the link and rotate it initially, so it does not appear on screen. Then, when the link is clicked, I rotate the parent the other direction so that both children (link and input) are rotated and only the input field is visible.

This works just fine, but the problem is that the input field is not clickable after the transition and I just don't get why or how to solve this.

Here are the important code parts:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <span class="rollover">
    <span class="rollover__front">
      <a href="#">Add a new article </a>
    </span>
    <span class="rollover__bottom">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Article number...">
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rollover,
.rollover__front,
.rollover__bottom
{
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.rollover
{
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin-z:-16px;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

.rollover--is-rolled
{
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg);
}

.rollover__bottom
{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  -webkit-transform-origin-z:-16px;
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
xonic

Answer (score 2):

I know this was a while ago, but incase you still are having this issue, I dealt with a similar problem. The reason is that the parent element does not have a Z thickness, so it does not think you are clicking an element. If you were to rotate it 180 degrees, then the backface of the parent element is there and the click is picked up. In order to make your animation work you would have to start with the bottom rotated -90 degrees and then on click rotate the top to 90 degrees and the bottom to 0 degrees. That way the parent is always visible.

**CSS**

```
.rollover,
.rollover__front,
.rollover__bottom
{
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.rollover__front,
.rollover__bottom{
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

.rollover
{
  height: 19px;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin-z:0px;
}

.rollover--is-rolled .rollover__bottom{
 -webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg);
}

.rollover--is-rolled .rollover__front{
  -webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg);
}

.rollover__front{
  position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    -webkit-transform-origin-z: -10px;
}

.rollover__bottom
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
-webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin-z: -30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div class="rollover">
    <div class="rollover__front">
      <a href="#">Add a new article </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rollover__bottom">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Article number...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a link with this working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqBsp